# Running Python Code in VS Code and Cannot Find Files in Same Folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I try to execute Python files from VS Code, it is unable to find other files in the same folder.

I am running OpenCV code in a test.py file with the following command :

```
filename = 'image1.png'
img1 = cv2.imread(filename)
print(img1)
```

The results should show an array of numbers but instead show **None** because VS Code cannot find **image1.png** which is in the same folder as the **test.py** file.

I have searched online for a solution but yet to find a clear one. I suspect I need to manually add this folder to a .json file, but this seems like a clunky solution for every time I need to run files all contained in the same folder.

(I support Monica - StackOverflows needs to stop being aggressive transgender crusaders.)

Comment: I think the folder you were at in the terminal is not this folder. If that's the case then use absolute path or path relative from projrct folder instead.

Comment: Good point. I'd suggest submitting this as the answer. How do I setup the relative path from the project folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think the folder you were at in the terminal is not this folder. If that's the case then use absolute path or path relative from projrct folder instead.

Change the `image1.png` to `./image1.png` should do as well.

If the project folder looks like

```
projectfolder
    |
    subfolder 
        |
        main.py
        image.png
```

And the terminal is at `projectfolder` then relative path of `image.png` is `projectfolder/image.png`.

Thogh, use `./image.png` is way less troublesome if the picture is always there, but if it's not then absolute path(like `/home/user/projectfolder/folder/image.png`) will eventually reduce time needed for debug.